# JSON Error: End of input at character 0 of, then works?

Tags: php, android, json, nullpointerexception

I am receiving two different errors one on the first run, one on the second. I haven't seen this before and I honestly don't know enough to say what's going on. I'll show the code, then the errors, and then the lines the errors are pointing to.

```
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_STORE = "store_info";
private static final String TAG_NUMBER = "store_num";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_CITY = "city";
private static final String TAG_STATE = "state";
private static final String TAG_ZIP = "zip";

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_basic_info, container, false);
        ab = getActivity().getActionBar();

        store_model = new Store_Model();
                ...
}

class Store extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray store_info = null;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading questions. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // getting JSON string from URL
            String componentName = (String) ab.getSelectedTab().getText();
            companyName = Store_Fragment.model.getcName();
            projectName = Store_Fragment.model.getpName();
            storeNum = store.getText().toString();
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company", companyName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("project", projectName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("component",
                    componentName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("store", storeNum));

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST",
                    nameValuePairs);
            // Check your log cat for JSON response
            //Log.d("All Store Info: ", json.toString());
            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.v("RESPONSE", "Success!");
                    // products found: getting Array of Store Info
                    store_info = json.getJSONArray(TAG_STORE);

                    // looping through Store Info
                    for (int i = 0; i < store_info.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = store_info.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each JSON item in variable
                        String number = c.getString(TAG_NUMBER);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String city = c.getString(TAG_CITY);
                        String state = c.getString(TAG_STATE);
                        String zip = c.getString(TAG_ZIP);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_NUMBER, number);
                        map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                        map.put(TAG_CITY, city);
                        map.put(TAG_STATE, state);
                        map.put(TAG_ZIP, zip);                      
                    }

                } else if (success == 0) {
                    // no questions found
                    Log.v("ERROR", "No JSON for you!");
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            error.setText("Invalid Store Number");
                            error.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                                    R.color.red_bg));
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
            // dismiss the dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();

                store_model.setStoreNum(map.get(TAG_NUMBER));
                store_model.setAddress(map.get(TAG_ADDRESS));
                store_model.setCity(map.get(TAG_CITY));
                store_model.setState(map.get(TAG_STATE));
                store_model.setZip(map.get(TAG_ZIP));


            Dialog_Fragment df = new Dialog_Fragment();
            df.show(getFragmentManager(), "store");
        }
    };
```

So the first time I run this it has trouble with the `JSON` and gives me this error.

```
06-18 17:21:17.870: E/json data(23746): json result 
06-18 17:21:17.870: E/JSON Parser(23746): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Then if I don't compile the code again, but just launch the app again from my tablet it gets to this screen and gets the `JSON` response, but gives me a null pointer.

Here is the JSON response and both logcats.

**JSON**

```
{
  "store_info":
   [
    {
      "store_num":"00607",
      "address":"790 W BROADWAY RD",
      "city":"TEMPE",
      "state":"AZ",
      "zip":"85282"
    }
   ],
   "success":1
}
```

**1st Run Logcat**

```
06-18 17:21:17.870: E/json data(23746): json result 
06-18 17:21:17.870: E/JSON Parser(23746): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
06-18 17:21:17.870: W/System.err(23746): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 17:21:17.870: W/System.err(23746):    at com.fa.BasicInfo_Fragment$Store.doInBackground(BasicInfo_Fragment.java:105)
06-18 17:21:17.870: W/System.err(23746):    at com.fa.BasicInfo_Fragment$Store.doInBackground(BasicInfo_Fragment.java:1)
06-18 17:21:17.870: W/System.err(23746):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-18 17:21:17.870: W/System.err(23746):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-18 17:21:17.870: W/System.err(23746):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-18 17:21:17.870: W/System.err(23746):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-18 17:21:17.870: W/System.err(23746):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-18 17:21:17.870: W/System.err(23746):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-18 17:21:17.890: D/AndroidRuntime(23746): Shutting down VM
06-18 17:21:17.890: W/dalvikvm(23746): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41093930)
06-18 17:21:17.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23746): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 17:21:17.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23746): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 17:21:17.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23746):    at com.fa.BasicInfo_Fragment$Store.onPostExecute(BasicInfo_Fragment.java:156)
06-18 17:21:17.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23746):    at com.fa.BasicInfo_Fragment$Store.onPostExecute(BasicInfo_Fragment.java:1)
06-18 17:21:17.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23746):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
06-18 17:21:17.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23746):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
06-18 17:21:17.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23746):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
06-18 17:21:17.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23746):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 17:21:17.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23746):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 17:21:17.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23746):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-18 17:21:17.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23746):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 17:21:17.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23746):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 17:21:17.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23746):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-18 17:21:17.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23746):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-18 17:21:17.900: E/AndroidRuntime(23746):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**2nd Run Logcat**

```
06-18 17:22:19.910: E/json data(23841): json result {"store_info":[{"store_num":"00607","address":"790 W BROADWAY RD","city":"TEMPE","state":"AZ","zip":"85282"}],"success":1}
06-18 17:22:19.910: V/RESPONSE(23841): Success!
06-18 17:22:19.930: D/AndroidRuntime(23841): Shutting down VM
06-18 17:22:19.930: W/dalvikvm(23841): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41093930)
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841):    at com.fa.Dialog_Fragment.onCreateDialog(Dialog_Fragment.java:39)
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841):    at android.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:398)
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-18 17:22:19.940: E/AndroidRuntime(23841):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So now the lines I assume these errors are pointing to.

**Error Log 1**

com.fa.BasicInfo_Fragment$Store.doInBackground(BasicInfo_Fragment.java:105)

```
int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
```

com.fa.BasicInfo_Fragment$Store.onPostExecute(BasicInfo_Fragment.java:156)

```
store_model.setStoreNum(map.get(TAG_NUMBER));
```

These errors seem self explanatory. You can't see if it was successful with the `TAG_SUCCESS` so therefor it crashes when trying to `setStoreNum` because that value is `null`. However when I run it the 2nd time it just works? That doesn't seem to make sense to me. It also then gives me this error.

**Error Log 2**

com.fa.Dialog_Fragment.onCreateDialog(Dialog_Fragment.java:39)

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder storeD = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    if (BasicInfo_Fragment.store_model != null) {

        mStore = BasicInfo_Fragment.store_model.getStoreNum();
        ...

        store = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.store_d);
        ...

        store.setText("Store #: " + mStore); <-- LINE 39
        ...

    }
```

Error Log 2 seems to be getting to my Dialog Fragment and then crashing when it tries to create. It's getting a null pointer exception from the mStore variable as marked but it's supposed to be checking for null before it even starts, very frustrating.

So I know this is a pretty lengthy post but I was trying to supply all the info and make this an easy read.

Please help me figure out why this is not getting my `JSON` the first time. Then all of a sudden working if I don't compile again but crashing with a null pointer on the onCreate for my Dialog_Fragment.

**PHP** just for good measure so you can see how the `JSON` is being created

```
<?php

require 'connect.php';
require 'mysql_queries.php';

if ($query_run = mysql_query($store_info_query)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($query_run) == NULL) {
        $response["success"] = 0;          
        echo json_encode($response);

    } else {
        $response ['store_info'] = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            $info = array();
            $info['store_num'] = $row['column1'];
            $info ['address'] = $row['column2'];
            $info ['city'] = $row['column3'];   
            $info ['state'] = $row['column4'];
            $info ['zip'] = $row['column5'];        

            array_push($response["store_info"], $info);                     
        }
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1; 
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);        
    } 
} 

?>
```

Comment: I think your `JSON` is not valid `JSON`. Check it out (comma behind `JSONArray` and missing semi-colon behind success tag).

Comment: @Sajmon well the `JSON` is being created by `PHP` and is the same for other `Activities`. They all work fine. Plus this works if I simply don't compile it again. Which is odd. All the same I will post the `PHP` so you can see how this is being done, if you have a suggestion on how to get a better response I will use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wich library do you use ? pls use the specific android libs

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject; 
...
```

Comment: I am using those **exact** libraries. I'm not using `Jackson` or `GSON` which would probably actually be easier.

Comment: hum.. btw are you in the right context at getActivity()? <- my_ctx.getActivity()

Comment: ok BasicInfo_Fragment calls Dialog_Fragment and Dialog_Fragment calls BasicInfo_Fragment.store_model.getStoreNum(); right? .. 
how should this work? is store_model static ?

Comment: yep, `public static Store_Model store_model = null;` and then it's given value later

Comment: I have seemed to magically solved the first half of this question. I am now getting the JSON everytime. However this problem still exists. I am posting a new question for the exact problem. I will link it here when it's created so you have a reference

Comment: here is the link to the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180667/null-pointer-in-dialog-fragment

Comment: well, I feel a little silly, but your original assumption about the wrong context was correct. I was using getActivity(), when I should of been using view.findView... Anyways answer accepted, thank you for your help and your time